# Data preparation before running exact logistic (elrm in R)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I started out using Firth's logistic (logistf) to deal with my small sample size (n=80), but wanted to try out exact logistic regression using the elrm package. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the "collapsed" data required for elrm to run. I have a csv that I import into R as a dataframe that has the following variables/columns. Here is some example data (real data has a few more columns and 80 rows):

```
+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------+
| patien_num | asymmetry | age | female | field_strength |
+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------+
|          1 |         1 |  25 |      1 | 1.5            |
|          2 |         0 |  50 |      0 | 3              |
|          3 |         0 |  75 |      1 | 1.5            |
|          4 |         0 |  33 |      1 | 3              |
|          5 |         0 |  66 |      1 | 3              |
|          6 |         0 |  99 |      0 | 3              |
|          7 |         1 |  20 |      0 | 1.5            |
|          8 |         1 |  40 |      1 | 3              |
|          9 |         0 |  60 |      1 | 3              |
|         10 |         0 |  80 |      0 | 1.5            |
+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------+
```

Basically my data is one line per patient (not a frequency table). I'm trying to run a regression with asymmetry as the dependent variable and age (continuous), female (binary), and field_strength (factor) as independent variables. I'm trying to understand how to collapse this into the appropriate format so I can get that "ntrials" part required for the elrm formula.

I've looked at https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/exact-logistic-regression/ but they start with data in a different format than mine, and having trouble. Any help appreciated!

Comment: How would your collapsed data look like? How would the final output look like for these 10 rows?

Comment: I believe from reading the ucla link, basically you have one line for every combination of your independent variables (age, gender, field_strength), one column for the number of cases of your dependent variable (i.e. # of age 20, gender male, 1.5T with positive asymmetry) within that subset, and one column for the total number within that combination of independent variables (i.e. total # of age 20, gender male, on 1.5T). But if that's true, I'm not sure how to handle a continuous variable like age